# Missing OpenSSL header file in Mac

Tags: c++, package

When running cpp code using openssl (I was going to use `sha.h`), it says that it doesn't contain the file `<openssl/configuration.h>`. When I cd into the folder, I found that it had `configuration.h` in the directory only. I did not find `configuration.h` file.

I'm a Mac user. Does it have anything to do with Mac?

My openssl version is 3.1.2.

Comment: Use `brew` to install openssl.

Comment: "I found that it had configuration.h in the directory only. I did not find configuration.h file" - Read that again and then (hopefully) we can agree that it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it have anything to do with Mac?

No, it has nothing to do with Mac.

You should check if you have installed openssl successfully. Use the following command:

```bash
brew list | grep openssl
```

To list all installed openssl on your Mac. For example, my output:

```
❯ brew list | grep openssl
openssl@1.1
openssl@3
```

And you can print the default installation path with `brew --cellar`:

```
❯ brew --cellar
/usr/local/Cellar
```

And you can find the installed openssl in the directory. `cd` into the directory and find `include` path. For example, mine: `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.2/include/openssl`

And you can find `sha.h`:

```
❯ ls sha.h
sha.h
```